# Implementing Singleton using Prototype factory design pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs

We are loading a JavaScript file using *RequireJS* and it is like:

```
define([],function(){

    function xMode(){
        Y.call(this);
    }
    xMode.prototype = Object.create(Y.prototype);
    xMode.prototype.constructor = xMode;

    xMode.prototype.samplFn = function(data){
        var self = this;
        Y.prototype.samplFn(this,data);
    }
    var x=new xMode();
    return x;
});
```

Y is another file which is having some prototype methods

when I am trying to call xMode on every click, it stores last request data.
As Per my understanding, it creates x instance only once (or) the requirejs loads this file only once and every time gives the same instance.(it means it is following singleton design pattern)

Help me to Create individual instance for each and every request or click

Comment: There is no point in using prototypes for singleton objects.

Comment: "*I am trying to call xMode on every click*" - show us that code! And no, you don't want a singleton pattern if you need individual instances.